# Vue2 props Property does not exist on type 'Readonly{}>'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am struggling with prop type at vue.

Using Vue(2.6.11) + CompositionAPI(1.6.2) + Typescript(4.6.3)

```js
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script lang = "ts">
    import ...

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'componentName',
        props: {
            foo: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        setup(props) {
            const state = reactive({
                bar: props.foo // TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Readonly{}>'
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

In my knowledge, `setup(prop)` in vue do type inference automatically.
[Vuejs docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props)

How can I fix the typescript error?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? Editor? `build` command?

Comment: command(```npm run serve```), and IDE(Webstorm) both occur error